# Dimension of subspaces by the replacement theorem.

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

I'm trying to show that given a subspace $W$ of a finitely generated vector space $V$, we have $\dim(W) \leq \dim(V)$. I wanted to prove this with the replacement theorem, for reference

Replacement theorem:    Let $V$ be a vector space generated by a set $G$ containing exactly $n$ vectors, and let $L$ be a linearly independent subset of $V$ containing exactly $m$ vectors. Then $m \leq n$, and there exists some $H \subseteq G$ containing exactly $n-m$ vectors such that $L \cup H$ generates $V$.

So the plan was to let $\gamma$ be a basis of $V$ and $\beta$ be a basis of $W$. Because $\beta$ is a linearly independent subset of $V$ and $\gamma$ is a spanning set of $V$, the replacement theorem tells us that $|\beta| \leq |\gamma|$ hence $\dim(W) \leq \dim(V)$.

Are my assumptions and application of the replacement theorem OK? Thanks in advance for any clarifications!

Comment: Yeah, this seems fine. Note: all you're really using is the $m \le n$ conclusion in the Replacement theorem!

Comment: Ah ok perfect thanks!